# Condition Vars at POSIX

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

I am making a theatre - reservation application for a project. My theatre contains 10 operators, so everytime only 10 clients can make reservations simultaneously. When a client is done, another one is connected with an operator.

I have a server-client connection established. Everytime a new client appears i am creating a new thread. Now my problem is how to make 10 threads do their operation simultaneously. I know that i have to use condition vars but do not know how exactly.

What are my thoughts, whenever a client connects

```
lock mutex()
counter++;
if(counter > 10)
  block thread() until an operator is free
else
  do computations
unlock mutex()
```

I know i have to use cond_signal and cond_wait but i don't know how exactly. Any help?

Comment: Here's a hint:  "block thread" sounds like "wait on condition variable".  You should be able to figure out for yourself what "an operator is free" means.  (Hint 2: the operator becomes free becase some other thread freed it.  That thread probably should signal the condition var.)

Comment: P.S.: In the real world (i.e., not in a homework assignment), it might make more sense to have 10 fixed threads representing the 10 operators, and have the clients represented by objects in a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the threads:

```
sem_t *sem;
sem = (sem_t*)malloc(sizeof(sem_t));
sem_init(sem, 0, 10);
```

Inside the threads:

```
sem_wait(sem);

do computations
sem_post(sem);
```

The last parameter of sem_init is how many threads will be allowed to be executed.
Every time you call sem_wait that value is decreased and if it becomes <0 the thread is paused until it becomes again positive.
when you call sem_post that value is increased by 1 and a new thread can execute the inner code.

Comment: Well thanks, but it is a university project and in this part i'm not allowed to use semaphores. I have to make it work with mutexes & condition variables.

Comment: You could implement your own semaphore using mutexes and condition variables.